# Find the distribution of $ N = \min \left\{k: \prod_{i = 1}^{k}U_i \lt .6\right\}. $

Tags: probability, logarithms, uniform-distribution, poisson-process, exponential-distribution

**The Statement of the Problem:**

Let $ \{ U_i \}$ be a set (sequence?) of iid random variables such that $U_i \sim \text{Uniform}(0,1)$, and define

$$ N = \min \left\{k: \prod_{i = 1}^{k}U_i \lt .6\right\}. $$

Find the distribution of $N$.

**SOLUTION**

Recall that $-\log (U) \sim \text{Expo}(1)$. From this, it follows that

$$N = \min \left\{k: \prod_{i = 1}^{k}U_i \lt .6\right\} = \min \left\{k: \sum_{i = 1}^{k} \left[ - \log ( U_i ) \right] \gt \log \left( \frac{5}{3} \right) \right\} = \min \left\{k: S_k \gt \log \left( \frac{5}{3} \right) \right\} $$

where $S_k$ is the arrival time of the $k$th event of a Poisson process with rate $\lambda = 1$. I understand all of this. Beyond this point is where I get confused...

Now, it follows (apparently) that the smallest $k$ such that $S_k \gt \log \left( \frac{5}{3} \right)$ is

$$ N\left[ \log \left( \frac{5}{3} \right) \right] + 1 \qquad (*) $$

which is distributed as $\text{Poisson}^{ \left( \log \frac{5}{3} \right) } + 1$.

I'm not sure what is meant by this sort of "superscript" parameter here (I'm transcribing this from handwritten notes). As far as I can tell, it's just a normal ol' parameter. Anyway, I have no idea where the result $(*)$ comes from, and have been racking my brain here trying to figure it out. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: The smallest $k$ such that $S_k>a$ is $1+N(a)$ where, for every positive $a$, $N(a)$ is a random variable whose distribution is Poisson with parameter $a$.

Comment: Ah. Hmm. I've never seen that before. Is this a common result? If so, where does it come from?

Comment: Yes. The computation is not that hard, starting from the fact that, for every $n$, $[N(a)=n]=[S_n\leqslant a<S_n+X_{n+1}]$, where $S_n$ and $X_{n+1}$ are independent with known distributions. Every introductory course on Poisson processes presents it. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_point_process#Counting_process_interpretation